You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword. when making grid in unity
i am attempting to spawn a grid over some tiles and have it weed out tiles that cant be walked on. but it just keeps saying You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent(). im not sure how to fix this. ive tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to be working.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class GridLines : MonoBehaviour

{
   Node[,] grid;
   [SerializeField] int width = 25;
   [SerializeField] int length = 25;
   [SerializeField] float cellSize = 1f;
   [SerializeField] LayerMask obstacleLayer;

   private void Start()
   {
    GenerateGrid();
   }

   private void GenerateGrid()
   {
     grid = new Node[length, width];
     CheckPassableTerrain();
    }

   private void CheckPassableTerrain()
   {
        for (int y =0; y < width; y++)
        {
      for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
        {
            Vector3 worldPosition = GetWorldPosition(x,y);
          bool passable = Physics.CheckBox(worldPosition, Vector3.one /2 * cellSize, Quaternion.identity, obstacleLayer);
          grid[x,y] = new Node();
          grid[x,y].passable = passable;
        }  
    }
     }  

   private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
      if (grid == null) 
      {
        return;
      }
    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++)
    {
      for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
            {
                Vector3 pos = GetWorldPosition(x, y);
                Gizmos.color = grid[x,y].passable ? Color.white : Color.red;
                Gizmos.DrawCube(pos, Vector3.one);
            }
        }
   }

    private Vector3 GetWorldPosition(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Vector3(transform.position.x + (x * cellSize), 0f, transform.position.z + (y * cellSize));
    }

}


ive tried adding it as a game object and component as well as what unity suggests i add. but ether i messed up along the way or something cause i couldnt get it to work.

As it says, assuming from your code Node is a monobehavior, which sounds unnecessary from the code youve shared, you need to add it to the gameobject with AddComponent.  Its more likely you dont need to have it descend from Monobehavior.. Do you need it to appear on game objects, or is it just a memory item? if its just to be in memory (like a list of phone numbers, or other data values) then remove the ": MonoBehavior" from the node.cs file.

I do need it to appear on game objects yes. I am using it to see what tile can and cant be walked on then used when the player is moving.

No you have an array of data that knows that.  Otherwise whats the point of the grid array?

You were right i needed to remove monobehavior. the gizmos still aren't being drawn and colored but that's another problem i gotta solve.

This is because Monobehaviors cannot exist without their respective GameObject, as they are GameObject components.
From the docs:

MonoBehaviour is a base class that many Unity scripts derive from.
MonoBehaviours always exist as a Component of a GameObject, and can be instantiated with GameObject.AddComponent.

To make your GridLines work, just drag it to the GameObject of interest in the editor, or with code:
public class OtherComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<GridLines>();
    }
}


If type Node is a Monobehaviour type, you must Instantiate its prefab. (if it inherits from Monobehaviour)
Otherwise, you can remove the inheritance if you don't need that Monobehaviour functionality in the Node class.
Also see this.

i'm still a bit new to coding and learning would you be able to show me what you mean? like what would i need to add exactly to get it running.

Can you show Node code?
